# Implementing delegate methods in separate class

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I created delegate and its methods are the same to every VC that it supports. How can I use with out code duplication?

My code

#pragma mark - UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate

```
 (id <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationControllerForPresentedController:(UIViewController *)presented presentingController:(UIViewController *)presenting sourceController:(UIViewController *)source
{
CircularTransitionAnimator *animator = [CircularTransitionAnimator new];
animator.isPresenting = YES;
self.pointForAnimationOfViewUserPhotos = point;
animator.actionPoint = point;
return animator;
}

-(id <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationControllerForDismissedController:(UIViewController *)dismissed
{
CircularTransitionAnimator *animator = [CircularTransitionAnimator new];
animator.isPresenting = NO;
animator.actionPoint = self.pointForAnimationOfViewUserPhotos;
return animator;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a separate class dedicated to the delegate methods, or use a view controller subclass, which every other VC will inherit from.

Comment: How can I do the first case? The second I understand

Comment: Just create a new NSObject subclass, let it implement those methods.Instantiate that class in every VC and assign it as the delegate.

Answer (score 0):

As @rounak suggests you can create a separate class dedicated for handling the delegation.

*Example*

Create an NSObject subclass and adopt UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate and add & implement the delegate methods.

In you VC assign your new object as the `transitioningDelegate`

Comment: I need class for methods implementation